# finding third functional dependency and its candidate keys

Tags: data-structures, database-theory, relational-algebra

i'm solving a multi part question regarding candidate keys and functional dependencies.

now i've already found 2 dependencies(the canonical covering of the functional dependencies contains only 3 dependencies) in the previous parts of the question:  $D\to BE, CE \to AD$ ($R=A,B,C,D,E$, R is in BCNF). how can i find the third and last one? i need to find in order to figure the candidate keys

(didn't post the previous part of the questin because they're irrelavant, just posted what i found and all the needed information from the question).

thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Which are the initial given dependencies? D->BE and CE->AD?  Then there are four dependencies in the canonical cover, not three (and the relation is not in BCNF).

Comment: thank you for replying @Renzo. i was given D->BE, found CE->AD and there should be one more dependency i should find and i am not sure how. it is said that the canonical covering consists of only 3 dependencies and R is in BCNF

Comment: don't know how to find the remaining dependency

Comment: I need all the original depedencies, there is only D->BE? So how did you find CD->AD?

Comment: obtained it from a previous sub question about database modeling(entity design).

how is it possible to know what is the third one after D->BE and CD->AD?

Comment: What Renzo said: please give all the dependencies from the original question(s). Don't mix it up with any dependencies you've derived. And the dependencies mentioned in these comments seem to be different to the o.p.?